# How to check for currency code in php variable?

Tags: php

I want to know what currency code lies in my variable value.

**For example:**

```
$var = "$200";
$check = array("$", "AU$", "CA$", "£", "€", "¥");

If $var has "$"
$currency = USD

else if $var has "£"
$currency = GBP

and so on..
```

What I was trying is:

```
$result = strpos($var, $check);
if ($result === '$') {
$currency = 'USD';
} else if ($result === '£') {
$currency = 'GBP';
| else ...
```

Comment: But AU$ has $ as well. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with `strpos` but it only check for existence, I don't know how to get containing value. Can we check AU$ and CA$ as it is?

Comment: By that I mean you should update your question with the current code you're trying this with. We can look over it and point out where it is going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```
$var = "$200";
$check = array("$"=>'USD', "AU$"=>'aus', "CA$"=>'cas', "£"=>'GBP', "€"=>'ee', "¥"=>'yy');

$symbol = str_replace(range(0,9),'',$var);

$currency = $check[$symbol]?$check[$symbol]:'';
```

Comment: Just FYI, this code will need some tweaks to work with numbers like $83.33 or $AU832,733,99.  If you have those type of numbers you can easily tweak this, so long as you understand what Feroz did here, and why it works.

Comment: I'll strip the later value for the simplicity :) I didn't notice that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an associative array of your currencies and then use the php function array_search to see if the currency you have selected is present in the currencies array.

```
<?php

$currencies = array(
    'USD' => '$',
    'AUD' => 'AU$',
    'GBP' => '£'
);

$mycurrency = '£';

$key = array_search($mycurrency, $currencies);

if($key) {

    echo 'My currency is ' . $key;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match()` and a regular expression fit the bill just fine here:

```
$curr = "$250000";
$sign = null;
preg_match('/\$|AU\$|CA\$|£|€|¥/', $curr, $sign);
switch($sign) {
    case '$':
        // USD
    case 'AU$':
...
```